# extending class and protected data

Tags: php

im trying to create a class to manage widgets. I have problems with a protected data in parent class:

Widget.php

```
/** Parent class **/
class Widget{
    protected $html =""; //formated html data
    // method to load views in {system_path}/widgets/{widget_name}/views/
    protected function LoadView($filename){
        if(!empty($filename) && is_string($filename)){
            $output = "";
            $dir = WIDGET_PATH . "views" . DS . $filename;
            ob_start();
                include($dir);
                $output = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $output;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    //method to render formated html data
    public function Render(){
        if(isset($this->html) && !empty($this->html)){
            return $this->html;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    //static method to load a Widget
    public static function Load($widgetName){
        if(!empty($widgetName) && is_string($widgetName)){
            $widgetName = strtolower($widgetName);
            if(file_exists(WIDGET_PATH . $widgetName . DS . $widgetName . ".php")){
                include_once(WIDGET_PATH . $widgetName . DS . $widgetName . ".php");
                if(class_exists($widgetName."_Widget")){
                    $class = $widgetName."_Widget";
                    return new $class();
                }
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

/widgets/socialbar.php

```
/** SocialBar Widget **/
class Socialbar_Widget extends Widget
{   
    public function __construct(){
        $this->html = "demo"; // test to see if it works
    }
}
```

index.php

```
/*load class files, etc */
$Social = Widget::Load("socialbar"); //works, perfectly loads Socialbar_Widget()

var_dump($social); // works : object(Socialbar_Widget)[29] protected html = 'demo' ......

$Social->Render(); // throws Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

To extend a variable inside parent class should i use "public"? Or what i mistake.
Thanks for help guys.

Comment: Are you certain your `load()` method isn't returning false?

Comment: `Using $this when not in object context` comes from calling a non-static method in a static manner. Looks like there's something else to blame here. Can you try and give a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @JohnConde yes, i exec a var_dump and isnt false

Comment: I have copied your code and tried it and my Render-method works perfectly. I cannot seem to find the problem with your code.

Comment: @cbuckley i only have 3 files and i copied it here, im running it minimal

Comment: @StefanLuv the code you posted here would not (indeed, could not) generate the error you posted. The code above is not self-contained either, since `WIDGET_PATH` and `DS` are not defined in it (though we can infer their meaning). Try enabling `E_STRICT` errors, as that will give you something like `Non-static method ClassName::FunctionName() should not be called statically`.

Comment: When you var_dumped $social, shouldn't it give `protected html = 'demo'` instead of `protected html = ''`? Seems like there is something else going on here.

Comment: @cbuckley ill try with E_STRICT. I was thinking, the problem can be PHP Version? im using WAMPSERVER (in windows)

Comment: @StefanLuv any PHP 5 version should run this fine. Note that `E_STRICT` is not part of `E_ALL` in PHP < 5.4.0. @supericy's comment is an interesting one, might be worth looking at if that is indeed the correct var_dump output.

Comment: @Supericy sorry buddy, i forgot copy that, yes it gies ='demo', i changed it

Comment: @cbuckley well, i dont understand... i set E_STRICT, restarted server and works perfect

Comment: The code above will definitely **NOT** trigger the error message you see. Are you sure that you included or required the correct files? maybe what you see is from an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class name is class Socialbar_Widget,
Your are calling it in lower case

```
$Social = Widget::Load("socialbar")
```

and in load method you are doing strtolower($widgetName).
Check  class file name.php. Load function may have returning false.